# How do I add an ip range to aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce

I haven't found anything that details out how to add a range through the AWS portal. I have a range of salesforce ids that I need to add. When i set the server to only allow from specific ids I'm unable to reach the server by adding the basic single addresses. I found an address in the first range which allowed traffic, but when I've restricted access to only the listed ips I'm unable to ping salesforce from the server. I have all outbound traffic allowed. Also, when I allow all traffic, I am able to ping in both directions. I have very limited network experience, so any help is appreciated. Here is an example of the first ARIN range 13.108.0.0 - 13.111.255.255

Comment: For that range add this cidr range to your inbound security group 13.108.0.0/14. For outbound security rules allow all. Make sure you specify ghe correct protocol.

Comment: You can use this web site to calculate your CIDR ranges. https://www.wmtips.com/tools/subnet/13.108.0.0-13.111.255.255

Comment: Thanks! that worked.

Comment: Glad it is working, I have updated the answer. If you have found it useful can you mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a range like 13.108.0.0 - 13.111.255.255 first convert that to a CIDR range using a web site that can do the conversion: [wmtips](https://wmtips.com/tools/subnet/13.108.0.0-13.111.255.255)

Then add the CIDR address to the inbound rules of the security group attached to your EC2 (Make sure the correct protocol is selected). This is to allow access for the remote system. Set the outbound rules on the security group to 0.0.0.0/0.